# Google Calendar Javascript API listing ALL events from ALL calendars

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-plus

I can list a selected calendar events by adding the calendarID to the script:

```
   var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({ 
       'calendarId': 'primary'
    });
```

this gets the primary calendar  and by swopping out the 'primary' to the calendar id required

```
   'calendarId': '?????????????????@group.calendar.google.com'
```

But what I would like to do is list ALL events from ALL calendars, so is there away to do this like below for EG:

```
    'calendarId': 'ALL'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`primary` is the only special value that the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/reference.html#method_calendar_events_list) specifies. If the Calendar API does support such a special value, it is not publicly supported, and could be removed or changed at any time.

Your best option is to the [calendar.calendarList.list](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/reference.html#method_calendar_calendarList_list) method to get a list of all the users calendars and list the events from each one.

Comment: thanks fro this I presumed not and I would have to go around it the long way